# Firefox no support for <hr> tags in email client

Tags: html, email, firefox

Hope I can get some help with an HTML email that I am trying to bug fix. It seems that `<hr>` tags have very little support and I'm having trouble with any clients display via Firefox. I've been trying to figure out what a good alternative would be.

Since the HTML emails are adverts that members place with us, I make use of these tags in about 12 areas in the design and I would prefer a line that can grow horizontally according to the email clients width. Also, I would prefer that the line does not take more vertical space than the `<hr>` tag.

Comment: You could just use a border bottom or top of 1px solid grey?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I found a solution with a little more Googling. Here's the code I used for anyone looking for a quick fix:

```
border-bottom:1px solid white;
```